# Android apps, best practice when navigating views

Tags: android, android-studio

Being new to Android development and never having an Android phone, when user navigate to a new view, what is the best practice for a user to be back?

To elaborate, in iOS when user have a list of items, lets say contacts, when they click on the contact, they are navigated to the contacts details. On the top of the view their is some sort of back chevron (left side) and an Edit button (right side).

What is the "standard" or best practice for Android apps? I ask because of the fact that android apps have the three "soft" buttons where the first one is a "Back" button.

So back to my scenario, user has a list of contacts, user clicks on contact to navigate to detail view of contact, do they expect a back button on the left hand side or are they more accustom to just using the soft back button?

If the navigation button is not required on the top of the view, should the Edit button be located on the left side or should it still be on the right side?

Sorry for the newbie question but I am just trying to understand the best practices.

Answer (score 0):

Scenario with a list looks like a forward navigation.
You can find more details and guides on the [material design site](https://material.io/design/navigation/understanding-navigation.html#forward-navigation).

Also, you can find principles of navigation and difference between up and back buttons on [android developers.](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-principles)

I hope, the links provided above, will be useful.